# Port my current Google Chrome setup from old machine to new one

Tags: backup, google-chrome, portable

I have personalized my Google Chrome with a lot of extensions and customized settings here and there.

I extensively use the Session Manager extension that allows me to save the current session with a name - I have go around a lot of such sessions on my installation of Chrome.

What/how can I **port** the current setup that is on an older machine to the new one *especially* the saved sessions?

Also - For future - would any of you guys recommend any of the portable installations that you have used ( and in which you have reliably setup and ported extensions? )

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows 7 then

C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome

Backup that directory and replace it with the one on the new machine.

Alternatively you can use Google Chromes sync feature in Options > Personal Stuff > Sync

and then just enable it both on both machines, but through the method I don't think extension settings get saved.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an iGoogle account you can sync data between computers.

Go to **Options > Personal Stuff > Sync** and enable syncing.

You can configure what to synchronise:

[image]

I don't know about saved sessions though.